# Message structure in AWS SQS and SNS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I have a SNS topic `t1` that is subscribed into a SQS queue `q1`. I have a NodeJS process `p1` that publishes to `t1`, process `p2` that subscribes from `q1`. I also have a process `p3` that writes to `q1` directly.

Suppose, `data` is populated when `p2` reads from the queue. Then, while the following snippet works with `p1` as the writer to the queue, I get a JSON parser error with `p3`.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.Messages.length; i++) {
 var message = data.Messages[i];
 let messageBody = JSON.parse(message.Body)
 let payload = JSON.parse(messageBody.Message)
```

The only way I could process data from `p3` working is to *not* have `JSON.parse(messageBody.Message)` and process `messageBody` directly. Thus, it seems that, the message structure as received in a queue is different if the writer was a SNS topic subscription or a SQS writer.

Can you please advise if I can have a single NodeJS application that can process data from SQS regardless of what wrote into that queue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this will solve all your issues, but as a first step at least you probably want to do enable 'Raw Message Delivery'

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html

In this way, the messages that SNS puts in the queue won't have any additional properties added, and thus should match messages that are put in directly.